# Email attachment sometimes attached as a string in email body

Tags: go, email, base64, email-attachments

I have a go code that creates an excel file (using "github.com/tealeg/xlsx") on a daily basis.
The file is then encoded to base64 and sent as an attachment via email, using go-simple-mail.
This works fine 99% of the time, but once in a while the email is sent as a NOOP, with the xlsx file as a string in the email's body.

Here's my code:

```
func (n *EmailNotifier) verifyServerConnection() error {
    err := n.smtpClient.Noop()
    if err != nil {
        n.smtpClient, err = n.server.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (n *EmailNotifier) SendFileByEmail(ctx context.Context, addresses []string, file, filename, mailSubject, body string) error {
    mailFile := mail.File{
        Name:    filename,
        B64Data: file,
    }
    err := n.SendEmail(ctx, addresses, mailSubject, body, &mailFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (n *EmailNotifier) SendEmail(ctx context.Context, to []string, mailSubject string, body string, mailFile *mail.File) error {
    err := n.verifyServerConnection()
    if err != nil {
        nl.Log(ctx).WithValues().Error("Error connecting to SMTP server")
        return err
    }
    email := mail.NewMSG()
    email.SetFrom(n.server.Username).AddBcc(to...).SetSubject(mailSubject)

    email.SetBody(mail.TextPlain, body)
    if mailFile != nil {
        email.Attach(mailFile)
        if email.Error != nil {
            nl.Log(ctx).WithError(email.Error).WithValues("attachment error", "noop")
        }
    }
    err = email.Send(n.smtpClient)
    if err != nil {
        nl.Log(ctx).WithValues("subject", to).WithError(err).Error("Error sending email to")
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

And here is the problematic mail:

> NOOP
> Subject: xxxxx
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
> boundary=259435eabdfa9a8b5c048944afa23eb1b547d42281bd7269b93eeb559924
> Date: Wed, 18 Jan 2023 04:00:14 +0000
> Mime-Version: 1.0
> From: mailto:xxx@yyy.com
>
> --259435eabdfa9a8b5c048944afa23eb1b547d42281bd7269b93eeb559924
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> --259435eabdfa9a8b5c048944afa23eb1b547d42281bd7269b93eeb559924
> Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename="xxx.xlsx"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
> name="xxx.xlsx"
>
> UEsDBBQACAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARAAAAZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZS54bWxs0M9KxDAQx/G7
> T1Fy30y6gkhpuzdPCoIKXkMydoP5M2RG23172aJVcM/zyRfy6w9Lis0nVg4lD6rVRjWYXfEhT4N6
> eb7b3aqGxWZvY8k4qBOyOoxXvaPOlYqPtRBWCcjNkmLmztGgjiLUAbA7YrKsC2FeUnwrNVlhXeoE
> ZN27nRD2xtxAQrHeioVzcEdbUX0nvduS9FHjGvAOMGLCLAytbuHXpiAnwosvfo5/tGBNfBGvl00u
> HDY1z7Oer1e3N6aF14f7p/Wru5DPUzlUYw//Bhq/AgAA//9QSwcIO+98GtgAAABsAQAAUEsDBBQA....

Decoding this string to an xlsx file generates a valid file. I also tried logging any attachment errors - nothing in the logs.
also - no open issues about this in go-simple-mail

idea-
I am using NOOP to check the server connection, but I am setting the attachment and the recipient only later in my code. Is there any chance that somehow the recipient is set before the NOOP in verifyServerConnection and it messes it up?
Any other suggestions on how to further explore this issue will be welcomed